# ADSF/WIF interaction example

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, adfs, ws-federation, adfs3.0

I'm new to ADFS. So could someone give a brief example of interacting with this service (login and claim check) using WIF library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I've made a minimal [sample Web API project](https://github.com/stop-cran/ADFS-WIF-sample). It implements an authentication itself and a retrieval of user's email inside an ASP.Net controller. To make ADFS to return a email claim see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9415002/2858407).